# Gradle only contain "build" command?

Tags: maven, gradle

In the Maven, there are many command, like clean, compile, package and install.
But I don't find any more commands in the Gradle.
So, how to implement these functions in the  Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

"build" is a [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html) and it's simple to add tasks to your project. See [more_about_tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)

Plugins can also add Tasks, for instance [here](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) are all the tasks added when you `apply` the `java` plugin

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In Gradle, we have many commands like clean, compile, test, build etc

you can also create your own gradle commands by following [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html) documentation